# Scribes Editor and Slackware64 13.37 -- PyGTKSpell Cannot Be Found

Tags: slackware, configure, slackbuilds

I am trying to build Scribes in Slackware64 13.37 with XFCE and I am having a lot of troubles with the Python Binding for GTK Spell. I have gtkspell-2.0.16-x86_64-1 and pygtkspell-2.25.3-i486-3sl installed but, the autogen script does not seem to find it:

```
...
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib64/python2.6/site-packages
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib64/python2.6/site-packages
Checking for D-Bus (Python Bindings)... yes
Checking for PyGTK... yes
Checking for pygtksourceview2... yes
Error: Python bindings for gtkspell was not found.
configure: error: Error: Dependency check failed
```

I tried to put a link in the path mentioned there (**${prefix}/lib64/python2.6/site-packages**, even though I do not know where that ${prefix} points =S, so I assumed the lib64 is the one in /) because the modules for python2.6/site-packages are really located in

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtkspell.la
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtkspell.so
```

also, I tried pointing all the link all the way to **/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/**

```
site-packages -> /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0/
```

but no luck =(.

Is there a way to specify the path to pygtkspell? should I put those modules somewhere else?

I am out of ideas, so thank you very much for yours =)

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use 32-bit python bindings (`pygtkspell` `i486`) with a 64-bit (`x86_64`) python. You can run ix86 and x86_64 binaries on the same system, but you can't load ix86 and x86_64 libraries in the same executable. Linking the wrong binaries in the right place won't help: they're still the wrong binaries. You need to obtain 64-bit bindings (`pygtkspell-*-x86_64-*`), or if they're not available (but they probably are), run a 32-bit python.